# Overwrite in dat files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have  the follwoing bash code i

```
declare -A matrix
num_rows=6
num_columns=1
for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
for ((j=1;j<=num_columns;j++)) do
if [[ i -eq 1 ]]; then 
matrix[$i,$j]= echo $i 
else
matrix[$i,$j]= echo $j
fi
done
done  >> out.dat
```

This code directs the outputs to dat file
but the problem when I rerun the code, the old outputs are removed and replaced by the new outputs, How can I keep the old outputs and save the new too?

Answer (score 1):

```
 > "out.dat"
```

truncates the file to zero size, essentially removing all its content.

If you want to preserve the previous old file you can move it:

```
mv out.dat out.dat.old
> "out.dat"
```

If you want to preserve all the old files, you can save them with a reasonably unique names such as using the `date` command:

```
mv out.dat out.dat.old.$(date +%s%2N)
> "out.dat"
```

The truncation may or may not be necessary depending whether your rest of code expects an empty or creates one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: And if you want to append to same file without taking a backup, you can use `>> out.dat` instead. `>>` will append, instead of truncating and writing.

Comment: Thanks for your notes, I have added the code segment to my question. I tried to involve ' mv' command but it does not work well

Comment: `>` is a truncate and write operation. `>>` does an append i.e. it starts writing from the end of the existing file. Example : `echo "Line 1" >> test.txt; echo "Line 2" >> test.txt` will put `Line 2` after `Line 1` in `test.txt` without truncating the file. `echo "Line 1" > test.txt; echo "Line 2" > test.txt` will first truncate the file, that is remove any existing text, and then put the new text. So, in the `>>` case, the final contents of the file are `Line1 Line 2` while in the `>` case, the final contents is just `Line 2`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot